# Surjectivity of perturbed linear operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, linear-pde

Consider two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ and two linear bounded operators $A,B:Y\rightarrow Y$.

Suppose the following:
(1) Y is reflexive (or even uniformly convex);
(2) $X\cap Y$ is dense in $X$ and $Y$;
(3) for each $y^{*}\in Y^{*}$ we have
\begin{equation}
\Vert y^* \Vert_{Y^*}\sim \Vert A^*y^* \Vert_{Y^*}\sim \Vert B^*y^* \Vert_{Y^*};
\end{equation}
(4) for any $\epsilon>0$ the operator $A-\epsilon B:X\cap Y\rightarrow Y$ is surjective.

Does it follow that $A:X\cap Y\rightarrow Y$ is surjective ?

I could not find any reference to something similar to this. Also, I could not find a counterexample (actually I expect this property to be true). Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with $||y^{\ast}||_{Y^\ast}\sim ||A^{\ast}y^{\ast}||_{Y^{\ast}}||\sim ||B^{\ast}y^{\ast}||_{Y^{\ast}}||$?

Comment: Anyway, if we ignore the third requirement for a second (which is don't understand) the following works as a counterexample. Consider any reflexive Banach space $A$ and consider the reflexive Banach space $X=A\oplus A$, we also consider $Y=X$. Let $p_1$ denote the projection onto the first component and $p_2$ denote the projection onto the second component. Then, for each $\epsilon>0$ the operator $p_1-\epsilon p_2$ is surjective yet $p_1$ is not surjective.

Comment: @sein: I think $\sim$ simply means that the quotient is bounded away from zero and infinity. That rules out your example since $p_1^*y=0$ for suitable $y$.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are variable quantities, by $a\sim b$ I mean that there are some positive constants $c_{1}, c_{2}$ such that $c_{1}a\leq b \leq c_{2}a$. Condition (3) is important.  By (3) we have already that the image of $A$ (the set $A(X\cap Y)$) is dense. It remains however to see if this image is also closed...